# Create model instance consisting of many-to-many field

Tags: python, django, ajax, post, model

I am trying to create a model instance using a post request, however one issue that I am having is that the model consists of a field which is of many-to-many. Now I am at a stage where I have got an array consisting of primary keys of the model instances (Modules) I wish to associate with the model I am trying to create (a Student).

Please see my code below as I do not know where I am going wrong, after some basic research it seems I need to use a `.set()` method.

The `PUT['modules']`  corresponds to `array` that consists of values `[1,2,3,5]`.

```
def create_student(request):
    """API for creating a student"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        PUT = json.loads(request.body)
        student = Student(name=PUT['name'], join_date=PUT['join_date'], academic_year=PUT['academic_year'],
                          modules=PUT['modules'] # THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                          )
        student.save()
        return JsonResponse(student.to_dict())

    return HttpResponseBadRequest("Invalid method")
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `PUT['modules']` is a list? A list of what? Primary keys?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem hello, yes a list of primary keys of the models (Modules) I am trying to associate with the model I am creating (Student). Thank you for your time.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so the idea is that a Student can have many Modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to populate a `ManyToManyField` relation, first the two items that you want to link need to be saved. This is necessary since otherwise these do not have a primary key: one links two items by adding a record in the *junction table* with the two primary keys to link.

If you thus want to link the `Student` you are constructing with the modules, you first create the `student`, and then you can use `student.modules.add(…)` to link it to the (existing) modules by unpacking a list of the primary keys of the modules:

```
def create_student(request):
    """API for creating a student"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        PUT = json.loads(request.body)
        student = Student.objects.create(
            name=PUT['name'], join_date=PUT['join_date'], academic_year=PUT['academic_year']
        )
        student.modules.add(*PUT['modules'])
        return JsonResponse(student.to_dict())
    else:
        # …
```